# Laravel - PHP Treating JSON object as a string from API

Tags: python, php, json, laravel

I have an API written in Python, which returns a JSON object. It looks like this:

```
{
   "Text":{
      "0":"Very unfriendly staff at reception: not responding to needs and giving wrong information.",
      "1":"The staff are polite, chatty and very helpful."
   }
}
```

This is the Python code, that returns it:

```py
import pandas as pd
def main():
   df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
   return df.to_json()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

In PHP, I use Laravel's [HTTP Client](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/http-client) to call my Python API.

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

class PythonAPI
{

    protected $response;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->client = Http::withHeaders([
           'Accept' => 'application/json',
           'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
        ]);
    }

    public function processCSVFile($fileContent)
    {
        $this->post('/app/ProcessUploadedFile');

        return $this;
    }

    public function post(string $endpoint)
    {

        $this->response = $this->client->POST(env('PYTHON_API_SERVER', 'http://localhost:5000/api/v1') . $endpoint);

        return $this;

    }

    public function getResponse()
    {
        return $this->response->json();
    }

}
```

I simply use this class like so:

```php
$api = new PythonAPI();
$data = $api->processCSVFile($fileContent)->getResponse();
```

If I try to `dd($data)`, I get:

```
"{
   "Text":{
      "0":"Very unfriendly staff at reception: not responding to needs and giving wrong information.",
      "1":"The staff are polite, chatty and very helpful."      
   }
}"
```

As you can see, the response is encapsulated with `" "`, and thus it is being treated as a string, instead of an array that Laravel's `json()` method should return ([See here](https://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Http/Client/Response.html#method_json)).

How can I successfully read the response from my Python API as a JSON object and not a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just decode the string to json with 
`$data = json_decode($data)`

Comment: That actually did the trick. Laravel's `json()` method already does this, but I guess it works when being applied two times?

Comment: Check if your python set correct Content-Type to application/json

Comment: It is, set via Flask (swagger)

Comment: Check with if(!is_object($data)) { $data = json_decode($data); }